# read_excel loop with multiple arguments

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I wrote a loop to read in every excel file within a directory and append it to a dataframe. It works.

```
file_list = glob.glob(path + "/*.xls")
for file in file_list:
   excl_list.append(pd.read_excel(file))
excl_merged = pd.concat(excl_list, ignore_index=True)
```

And, if I read in one file and pass in all the agruments I want, that also works. For example:

```
df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', usecoles=['code','name','date','hours'],skiprows= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

But, if I try to add those same arguments into my loop, it doesn't work. Any suggestions??

```
 file_list = glob.glob(path + "/*.xls")
    for file in file_list:
       excl_list.append(pd.read_excel(file,usecoles=['code','name','date','hours'],skiprows= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]))
    excl_merged = pd.concat(excl_list, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: What happens in the 3rd example? Is there an error? Do all your spreadsheets have those 4 columns?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work'? You have to be more specific. You should create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can understand what is going on.

Comment: Pretty sure you've got a typo in `usecol` **e** `s`

Answer (score -1):

```py
file_list = glob.glob(path + "/*.xls")

excl_merged = pd.concat(
                  [pd.read_excel(file,
                          # usecols, not usecoles
                          usecols=['code','name','date','hours'],
                          skiprows= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
                      for file in file_list
                  ],
                  ignore_index=True,
              )
```